# Progress Dialog

Tags: android

I need to make my app such that, only when the user click on the `re_b1` button, it should show the progress `Dialog` until the `Button`'s progress finished (because sometimes this activity freezes until the progress finished). Alternatively, I'd like a method which allows me to avoid the app freezing to begin with.

```
public class SOS extends Activity {

    public DB helper;
    public SQLiteDatabase sql;




    Spinner reg_gender;
    Spinner reg_Blood;

    GPSTracker gps;

    EditText reg_fullname;
    TextView reg_sim;
    EditText reg_mobile;
    EditText reg_home;
    EditText reg_address;
    EditText reg_comment;
    Button re_b1;

    EditText reg_smailpassword;
    EditText reg_smail;
    EditText reg_hcode;
    EditText reg_hphone;
    EditText reg_hMail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sos);


        helper=new DB(this);
        sql= helper.getWritableDatabase();



        // check if the user registered or not
        Cursor cur=sql.query("users", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cur.moveToNext()){
            sql.close();
            Intent call = new Intent(SOS.this, MainSos.class);
            startActivity(call);
            finish();
        }else{
            reg_Blood =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.reg_Blood);
            reg_gender =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.reg_gender);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  gender1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            reg_gender.setAdapter(gender1);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> blood1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.blood, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            reg_Blood.setAdapter(blood1);
            reg_mobile =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_mobile);
            reg_fullname =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);

            reg_sim =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reg_sim);
            TelephonyManager myt;
            myt = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String mob =  myt.getSimSerialNumber().toString();
            reg_sim.setText(mob);

            reg_home =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_home);
            reg_address =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_address);
            reg_comment =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_comment);

            reg_smailpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_smailpassword);
            reg_smail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_smail);
            reg_hcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_hcode);
            reg_hphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_hphone);
            reg_hMail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_hMail);

            reg_smailpassword.setText("administrator@!~");
            reg_smail.setText("ahmedelbadry1982@gmail.com");

            re_b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.re_b1);

            re_b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String name = reg_fullname.getText().toString();
                    String simn = reg_sim.getText().toString();
                    String mobile = reg_mobile.getText().toString();
                    String home = reg_home.getText().toString();
                    String address = reg_address.getText().toString();
                    String comment = reg_comment.getText().toString();

                    String smailpassword = reg_smailpassword.getText().toString();
                    String smail = reg_smail.getText().toString();
                    String hcode = reg_hcode.getText().toString();
                    String hphone = reg_hphone.getText().toString();
                    String hMail = reg_hMail.getText().toString();

                    // EditText validation
                    if (hMail.length() <= 0 || hphone.length() <= 0 || hcode.length() <= 0 || smail.length() <= 0|| smailpassword.length() <= 0 || name.length() <= 0  || simn.length() <= 0 || mobile.length() <= 0 || home.length() <= 0  || address.length() <= 0  ){
                        Toast.makeText(SOS.this, "All field are required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // insert new user in our table "users" in DB
                        long blo = reg_Blood.getSelectedItemId();
                        long gen = reg_gender.getSelectedItemId();
                        String blo1 = reg_Blood.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String gen1 = reg_gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("full_name", name);
                        cv.put("gender", gen);
                        cv.put("blood_type", blo);
                        cv.put("simno", simn);
                        cv.put("mobile", mobile);
                        cv.put("home", home);
                        cv.put("address", address);
                        if (comment.length() > 0 ) cv.put("comment", comment);
                        cv.put("email", smail);
                        cv.put("email_pass", smailpassword);
                        cv.put("code", hcode);
                        cv.put("phone_numb", hphone);
                        cv.put("email2", hMail);
                        sql.insert("users", null, cv);


                        //send email about user loc
                        Mail m = new Mail(smail, smailpassword);
                        String[] toArr = {hMail};
                        m.setTo(toArr);
                        m.setFrom(smail);
                        m.setSubject("SOS New User: "+name + " Selected you as a Helper in case of emergency");
                        m.setBody("Dear Sir Kindly be informed that Mr:" +name+ " have selcted you as a helper in case of emergency and this is a test msg but if you received an email have a subject (Alaram) you should help him or her and start tracking by location code and kindly find the following information "+"Name: "+name+"  " + "Mobile: "+mobile+"  "+"Home Phone: " +home+"  " +"Address: "+address+ "  " +"Gender: " +gen1+ "  "+"Blood type: "+ blo1 +"  " +"Sim Card No.: "+ simn+ "  "+ "Comment: "+comment);

                        try {
                            // m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation");

                            if(m.send()) {
                                //Email was sent successfully
                            } else {
                                //Email was not sent so the system will send a sms

                                String  msga1 =name+ "has select you as a helper " ;
                                gps.sendsms(hphone, msga1);
                            }
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            //There was a problem sending the email

                            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(SOS.this, "Registration is done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent call = new Intent(SOS.this, MainSos.class);
                        startActivity(call);
                        startService(new Intent(SOS.this ,SosSms.class));
                        finish();


                    }


                }
            });

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a good example of using `progress dialog`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814821/show-progress-dialog-android) Normally you would use this in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) but I don't see any network stuff going on so `runOnUiThread` may work for you. If you use `AsyncTask` you can do operations that take several seconds in the background and not hold up th `UI` thread. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you update your question and add this code? Much easier to read than in a comment