# Update UI Asynchronously in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3

I have a webservice call which is called every 10 seconds and should update a TextView with the webservice reply(or atleast show a toast message every 10 seconds)

But the UI is not getting updated at all.

Please find the code below.

```
public class MessagesRequestActivity extends Activity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String currentMsg="Default";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Calling the webservice
        getMessage();
    }
    public void getMessage(){

        try
        {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "getMessage");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        //Web method call
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://192.168.4.50/WebService.asmx");
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+ "getMessage", envelope);
        //get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        //the response object can be retrieved by its name: result.getProperty("objectName");
        String message = (String)response.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You are performing network operation on Ui thread try using Asynctask or a separate thread and you can use handler to show toast in worker thread

Comment: Or use Context.runOnUiThread() for the 2 UI update statements

Comment: @userSeven7s : Do you have sample on AsyncTask. I was not able to understand the progress bar sample. It is confusing.

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah Its simple.. Create the 'ProgressDialog' in `onPreExecute` and dismiss in `onPostExecute`.. Just google.. you'll find ample of examples.. this is too common..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an `AsyncTask`

```
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//do your work here
    return something;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
       // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
}
```

Then you can access by calling

```
TalksToServer varName = new TalkToServer(); //pass parameters if you need to the constructor
varName.execute();
```

[Async Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
[Progress Dialog Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814821/show-progress-dialog-android)

You don't want to do network stuff or call `sleep` on the `UI` thread. If it is an inner class then you will have access to your member variables of the outer class. Otherwise, create a contructor in the `AsyncTask` class to pass `context` if you want to update from `onPostExecute` or other methods besids `doInBackground()`.

Comment: This looks fine but how do I call this task repeatedly from UI Thread.

Comment: You would just have to create a new `Instance` of it and call `execute()` again. I guess I didn't see the "every 10 seconds" part. You could use a `Handler` to create a new instance and run it

Answer (score 4):

As everyone has mentioned, you're making network calls in the UI thread and performing Thread.Sleep() which freezes your UI.

I'd try something like this AsyncHttpClient class, it has all the functionality you need, you'll have to perform your UI updates in the callback.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/