# Android - AsyncTask or Thread while recovering data to SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, parsing, android-asynctask

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this work.

I'm developing an app in which I download data from a online txt, parse it and add it to my database. This is taking +-30 seconds, and there is only one part of the updater implemented.

When I try to use a Thread or Asynctask, I have problems when trying to pass the arguments to the void which is updating the Database.

**How can I implement it on the good way?**

Here is my code:

Main activity class:

```
public class Androideye_principal extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //WhazzupUpdate.DownloadWhazzup(AllUsers, TotalConnections);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_androideye_principal);

    PilotsSQLiteHelper pdbh = new PilotsSQLiteHelper(this, "PilotsDB", null, 1);

    SQLiteDatabase dbPilots = pdbh.getWritableDatabase();

    Context context = getApplicationContext();


    String TotalConnections = new String();
    WhazzupUpdate.DownloadWhazzup(dbPilots, TotalConnections, context);   




    dbPilots.close();


    CharSequence text = "Total Users: " + TotalConnections;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();

    [Continues with Buttons stuff and so on...]
```

Parser class:

```
public class WhazzupUpdate {

public static void DownloadWhazzup (SQLiteDatabase PilotsDB, String TotalConnections, Context context) {

    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("This is my url/whazzup.txt");

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++) {
        in.readLine(); }    // Go to the number of connections  
        TotalConnections = in.readLine();
        for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++) {
            in.readLine(); }    // Go to !CLIENTS
        PilotsDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM Pilots");

        while (((str = in.readLine()) != null) && !(in.readLine().contains("!AIRPORTS"))) {
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)

            String[] dataRow = str.split(":");

            if (str.contains("PILOT")) {
                ContentValues NewValue = new ContentValues();
                NewValue.put("VID", dataRow[1]);
                [More NewValue puts...]




            PilotsDB.insert("Pilots", null, NewValue);

            } //End IF Pilot


        } // End While
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}}
```

As you see, I call WhazzupUpdate.DownloadWhazzup Method in the main activity, and this is when all is getting frozen, but don't know how to derivate it to another threat and keep the references to the Data Bases and so on...

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A `Thread` or `AsyncTask` would be fine here. I prefer using `AsyncTask` for most of my heavy-lifting. You can create an `AsyncTask` and do your work in `doInBackground()` as it works on a background `Thread`. Then you can update your `UI` elements if needed in any of its other methods.

`onPostExecute()` will run after a result is passed from `doInBackground()`

`onProgressUpdate()` will run if you need to update `UI` during `doInBackground()` operations by calling `publishProgress()`. Here you can show a `ProgressBar` if you need to

and

`onPreExecute()` will run when you first call your task before `doInBackground()` runs.

Running the code in a background thread using `Thread` or `AsyncTask` will allow your `UI` to be free while the heavy work is being done.

[Example of AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297996/update-ui-asynchronously-in-android/15298134#15298134)

[Using interface with AsyncTask to post data back yo UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648)

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)