# Run a progress dialog while an other process is running

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am trying to run a progress dialog while an other process is running, and I can't do it.

the process that I want run is this:

```
public void Onclick_editar (View view)
{
    float porc;
    String repre;
    try{
        porc = Float.parseFloat(edit_porcentaje.getText().toString());
        repre = edit_representante.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            Hilo hilo;
            hilo = new Hilo(2, "UPDATE eleccion SET porcentaje="+porc+", delegados='"+repre+"' WHERE id="+idd );
            hilo.start();
            while(hilo.isAlive()){}

            hilo = new Hilo(4, idd);
            hilo.start();
            while(hilo.isAlive()){}
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Actualizada con éxito!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Fallo en la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                   
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Rellena todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this is launching when I click a button. thanks!

EDIT/////////////

well I solved the problem with this code!!

```
public void button(View v) {

     new waiting().execute();
```

}

```
  class waiting extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

      ProgressDialog progressdialog;
      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             super.onPostExecute(result);
             progressdialog.dismiss();

         }

      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground method
          progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Tab_adminver_modificar_eleccion.this);
          progressdialog.setTitle("Processing....");
          progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
          progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
          progressdialog.show();         
      }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
        return null;
    }

  }
```

but I don't use a toast in a method doInBackground (FC)

Comment: pls post the code that you tried and didn't run as expected, progess dialog's purpose essentially is mentioned in your question, can refer [a default progress dialog example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/) , [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814821/show-progressdialog-android)

Comment: sorry, i don't undestand you, I speak english a bit

Comment: try to run progress dialog -- post that code in question, refer the links in above comment

Comment: With assumption that Hilo is class derived from Thread code like `while(hilo.isAlive()){}` or `hilo.join();` in such cases make no sense becuase these calls block current thread so there is no use from new one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this your process will run in background and progress dialog will be executing as well but when process will complete progress dialog will dismiss..

```
public class asynTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    public asynTask1 (MainActivity activiy) {
        context = activiy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressdialog.dismiss(); 




    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Processing....");
        progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
        progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressdialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    // do process


}
```

U can call it `onclick` or also can `onCreate`.. it better to make separate class for asyntask1 and write 
`new asynTask1(MainActivity.this).execute();`  where you want to call it..

i hope it will helps ...

Comment: have I to call this class on my onclik method?

Comment: i have errors in: context cannot be resolved to a variable progressdialog cannot be resolved Splash cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: have you declared Context context = this;  and ProgressDialog progressdialog;  ... ???

Comment: thank you I have just understand the methods od preexecute, doinbackground....., but I have a force close when the process get to doinbackground, the dialog run before but after have an error. is there a problem in my code of the MySQL consult? really? I will try this with an other simple proccess

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you are waiting for `hilo` to finish in this line : `while(hilo.isAlive()){}`?

Use `AsyncTask` instead, make use of its `onPostExecute`

Comment: could you show me how do it in an example please? I don't understand too much about an asyncTask, thank you

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares Im afraid not in a short time, im working now. I will googling a little for you :)

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares this is quite simple with good explanation and source code : http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/ Just comment if u have some questions

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to show a ProgressDialog, then you can use this function for displaying a progress dialog-

```
public static void showProgressLoader(Context context, int duration)
{
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, duration);
}
```

In this finction, pass the context and duration in milliseconds for which you want to show, after that duration it will get dissmissed by itself.

Comment: yeah, but I dont know the duration for the other process, I want that this dialog will be closed when mysql consult fnish.

Comment: As of now you can pass 2 to 3 seconds but in that case, you have to call the dialog.dismiss() at the end of the Onclick_editar(View view) function.

Comment: i have errors in:
context cannot be resolved to a variable
progressdialog cannot be resolved
Splash cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

```
public void launchRingDialog(View view) {

    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading Image ...", true);

    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override

        public void run() {

            try {

                **// the MYSql consultation should be here?**

            } catch (Exception e) {



            }

            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }).start();
```