# Android RxJava AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, rx-java

With AsyncTask when processing array data we can easily deduce using AlertDialog progress bar processing.

Can this be done with the help of RxJava?  I ask you a simple example.

And how to solve the problem of turning devaysa when downloading data from the server using RxJava and display progress AlertDialog?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rx-alert-dialog](https://github.com/xavierlepretre/rx-alert-dialog) library solves this.

For example:

```
new RxAlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .title("Title")
    .message("Some action is required")
    .positiveButton("OK")
    .negativeButton("NO")
    .neutralButton("LATER")
    .show()
    .subscribe(new Observer(){
    ...
    })
```

In theory, you could call `setView()` on an `AlertDialog.Builder` to set a custom `View` that shows progress. However, this is considered bad practice and [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) is a better alternative.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814882/3848666) StackOverflow answer shows you how to use `ProgressDialog`.

Also relevant is the Material Design documentation about [progress](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html)