# Loading Alert box while getting response from server in android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app in which I need user login and registration. When user enters the login details and presses on Login button I want to display an alert box showing the loading spinner till it gets response from PHP script. I have tried lots of methods from internet but didn't work. I would be really thankful if you guys help!

Comment: what have you tried. add your code

Comment: `an box showing the loading spinner` ... these are different things.  Do you want a loading bar or an alert box?

Comment: this link might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814882/8164071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

when user click on login button

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "",
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

when you get response

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: copy paste from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814821/show-progressdialog-android/9814882#9814882